# Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i just started to do a sample webpage in ruby on rails.
i am getting an error "Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'" when i tried to post the image from a form.

my code is 
routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :posts 
root 'posts#index'  
end
```

posts_controll.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index  
    end
    def new  
        @post = Post.new
    end
    def create
        @post = Post.create(post_params)
        redirect_to posts_path  
    end
    private

    def post_params  
        params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption)
    end
end
```

newhtml.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :image %>
  <%= f.input :caption %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :image, presence: true
 has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

i didnt understand the error here. i think i have done all right.

please help me guys .

Comment: The error is clear but your code is not. "image_file_name" where did this came from?

Comment: Your images table simply does not have a field called image_file_name. If it had such a field then activerecord would create the attr_accessor for you. You should consider adding it through a migration.